# How to change Double value to String in barChart/swift?

Tags: ios, swift, graph, charts

Instead of showing the Double values in my chart I would like to show a String for each value. I still want the chart to draw from the Double values, but I want the label to show a string with a date instead. How to do this?

I´m using Daniel Cohen Gindis library.

```
Here is the code for my graph: 

import UIKit
import Charts

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var barChartView: BarChartView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //x line values
        let tools = ["Saw","Sissor","Axe"
            ,"Hammer","Tray"]

        //y line values
        let values = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]


        setChart(tools, values: values, colors: colors)

    }


    func setChart(xAxisLabels: [String], values: [Double], colors: [UIColor]){


        var dataEntries : [BarChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<xAxisLabels.count {

            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i )


            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }


        barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinValue = 0.0
        barChartView.leftAxis.axisMaxValue = 14.0



        barChartView.data = chartData

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code don't compile for me, can you update your code in order to help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String() method to convert any data type into a string.

For example:

```
var myDouble: Double = 1.5
print(String(myDouble)) // Prints "1.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need the answer, but this may help somebody who struggles with the same problem :)

First of all, you need to make a ValueFormatter class for your xAxis.

```
xAxis.valueFormatter = XAxisValueFormatter()
```

And then you have to put the following in your new class:

```
class XAxisValueFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value)
        let time = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date)

            return time
      }
}
```